# Range boosting with wifi access points

Tags: wireless-networking

One EA2700 connects to internet, can I use another EA2700 to repeat the signal to my room?

[More info on EA2700 router](http://support.linksys.com/en-mea/support/routers/EA2700)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A lot of routers can be converted into access points. I don't have much experience with linksys routers and their firmware (internal software), but in general you can follow this guide:

http://www.speedguide.net/articles/how-to-set-a-wireless-router-as-an-access-point-2556

This assumes that you use a wire to connect the routers. Because the EA2700 is a dual-band router there is a good chance that the Linksys software will allow for a wireless repeater mode.
I would not recommend buying the router for use as a repeater though, unless you've got one lying around and got time on your hands. It would be easier with your expertise to just buy a range extender. For good options, google and decide for yourself.

Comment: I went to buy another router, but bought range extender instead.